# Como puedo mantener el estado de los botones usando sharepreferences al rotar pantalla?

Tags: android

estoy tratando de mantener el estado de los botones al momento de girar la pantalla de portrair a landscape usando sharepreferences pero no logro hacerlo. Estuve intentanto con save Instance pero solo guardo el valor boolean con el que estoy trabajando pero no el estado del boton(ON/OFF y el background). Segun estuve leyendo usando sharepreferences en OnStop y OnStart deberia poder guardarse el estado pero no lo hace. Los botones sirven para activar el sensor de luz del dispositivo android.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lightSensorIsActive = false;

    // Get the references to the UI:
    bLight = findViewById(R.id.bLight); // button to start/stop sensor's readings
    tvSensorValue = findViewById(R.id.lightMeasurement); // sensor's values

    // Get the reference to the sensor manager and the sensor:
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    // Obtain the reference to the default light sensor of the device:
    lightSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);

    // Listener for the button:
    bLight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (lightSensorIsActive) {
                // unregister listener and make the appropriate changes in the UI:
                sensorManager.unregisterListener(MainActivity.this, lightSensor);
                bLight.setText(R.string.light_sensor_off);
                bLight.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_button_off));
                tvSensorValue.setText("Light sensor is OFF");
                lightSensorIsActive = false;
            } else {
                // register listener and make the appropriate changes in the UI:
                sensorManager.registerListener(MainActivity.this, lightSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
                bLight.setText(R.string.light_sensor_on);
                bLight.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_button_on));
                tvSensorValue.setText("Waiting for first light sensor value");
                lightSensorIsActive = true;
            }
        }
    });
}

// Methods related to the SensorEventListener interface:

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    // Show the sensor's value in the UI:
    tvSensorValue.setText(Float.toString(sensorEvent.values[0]));
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {
    // In this app we do nothing if sensor's accuracy changes
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("lightSensorIsActive", lightSensorIsActive);
    editor.commit();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    lightSensorIsActive = sharedPref.getBoolean("lightSensorIsActive", false);

}
```

}

Comment: No deberías recurrir a SharedPreferences para esto, sino modernizar tu código Android, implementando el paradigma MVVM y los [Componentes de Arquitectura de Android](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide), lo cual te permitirá un código en el que los valores no se destruyan al rotar la pantalla (esta es una ventaja mínima con respecto a todos los avances que suponen los Componentes de Arquitectura).